# Reasons to choose Rails 4.0 over 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to convince my colleagues to chose the latest version of Rails for a bunch of projects we starting but kinda out of arguments. None of the new features look very exciting so it doesn't looks like it's worth dealing with inevitable bugs in Rails themselves and gems.

Comment: So, you've just answered your question.

Answer (score 2):

Well if you use Postgres and hstore then the option to store an array instead of serializing it is super nice.

The new activerecord methods makes sense and and some irregularities have been attended, like stuff returning nil where they now return an empty relation, scoping returns relations rather than arrays so you can method chain it.

The new params protection somehow makes sense and you get used to it fairly quick.

Using concerns for service objects is somewhat nice, you can define a Tag like behavior and it can be included in all models so it also makes more sense.

I think that rails 4 has just matured a bit from rails 3 in the more making sense rather than delivering out-of-this-world features.

The one thing you should do if you chose either rails4 or rails3 is use Ruby 2.0, that is where the real improvement is, when you're using a threaded server you really see it shine as the copy-on-write bug has been fixed.

Answer (score 1):

For example I'm very glad that now there is such thing in Rails 4 as [ActionController::Live](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Live.html).

Comment: As far as I understand it starts a new thread instead of using an existing event loop of a multiplexing server like Thin so while cool it's not *that* cool.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the below link. It explains advance features in rails 4

**http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html**